# Graphing a Normal Vector to a Plane from the origin

Tags: vector

I'm trying to plot a normal vector to a plane. I know I'm doing something I should know better, but can't seem to find. Vectors {0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3} obviously determine a plane. Their Cross Product is {1, 2, -1}, which is normal. Unfortunately this code (all from the origin):

```
Graphics3D[{{Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2}}]}, {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, -2, 1}}]}, 
{Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 3}}]}}]
```

---

Yields,

[image]

Which doesn't look quite right. Just don't trust pictures? Any thoughts appreciated. Trying a different way I found some Mathematica code from a multivariable course for normals to a plane... and I got the same thing...

Comment: Check `BoxRatios`.

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
v1 = {0, 1, 2};
v2 = {-1, -2, 1};
v3 = Cross[v1, v2];
origin = {0, 0, 0};

Graphics3D[
 {Opacity[0.5], InfinitePlane[origin, {v1, v2}], Opacity[1],
  Blue, Arrow[{origin, v1}], Arrow[{origin, v2}],
  Red, Arrow[{origin, v3}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using option `AspectRatio` we can adjust the picture

```
Graphics3D[{{Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2}}]}, {Red, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, -2, 1}}]}, {Blue, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 3}}]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, AxesStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
  BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image]